# filtering dataframe using threshold level pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and I have a dataframe,df

```
 Index               eventName        Count      pct     
2017-08-09               ABC           24       95.00%         
2017-09-09               CDE          140       98.50%         
2017-09-22               CDE          150       99.30%         
2017-10-19               DEF          200       20.00%         
2017-10-27               DEF          200       50.00%
```

How can I filter the dataframe,df based on (50.00% and above) and not make column pct an index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), but for condition need remove `%` by slicing `str[:-1]` or by `replace`:

```
df1 = df[df['pct'].str[:-1].astype(float) >= 50]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[df['pct'].replace('%','', regex=True).astype(float) >= 50]
```

---

```
print (df1)
        Index eventName  Count     pct
0  2017-08-09       ABC     24  95.00%
1  2017-09-09       CDE    140  98.50%
2  2017-09-22       CDE    150  99.30%
4  2017-10-27       DEF    200  50.00%
```

Comment: I tried to group by monthly basis in order to count the values of the pct  belonging to the month. I used this code:

Comment: df2= df.groupby( [pd.Grouper  (key='df.index', freq='1M')]).df['pct'].size()
    print(df2)

Comment: but I get :KeyError: 'The grouper name df.index is not found'

Comment: I think you need only `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).size() `

Comment: Or more clean `df.resample('1M').size() `

Comment: I intend to have the index to be in words like August,September,October

Comment: then use `df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%B')).size()`

Comment: thanks,what about trying to plot a pie chart on this new dataframe: pyplot.pie(df.columns,labels=df.index, shadow=False, explode=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15), startangle=90,autopct='%1.1f%%', )
# View the plot drop above
pyplot.axis('equal')      
# View the plot
pyplot.tight_layout()
pyplot.show()        AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'column'

Comment: What about `df1.plot().pie(shadow=False, explode=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15), startangle=90,autopct='%1.1f%%', )` ?

Comment: how can I group by weekly day i.e.1st mon +2ndmon +3rdMon....then tues... wednes...using the size()

Answer (score 1):

import pandas 
df=df[df["pct"]>50.00]

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure? There are `%`, so your solution failed.